Diagonalization using pauli matricies
In our class, the professor easily diagonalizes a $2\times2$ matrix, claiming he "sees" it using a linear combination of Pauli matrices to represent the original matrix.
He couldn't explain how, but is there a connection between the eigenvalues, eigenvectors and Pauli matrices?

What's the matrix?

The Pauli basis $(1,\sigma_{1,2,3}$  of the 4-d space $\mathbb C^{2\times 2}$ is selected by its simple product rule
$$ \sum_{m=1}^3 a_m \sigma_m \quad  \sum_{n=1}^3 b_n \sigma_n =  \sum_{m=1}^3 a_m b_m + i \sum_{m=1}^3 (\vec a\times \vec b)_m \sigma_m )$$
The central point, trivializing the Clifford algebra $\mathit{Cl}(2,\mathbb C)$is
$$\sigma_i \sigma_k = \delta_{ik}, \quad  \text{Tr}\ 1 = 2 \quad  \text{Tr} \ \sigma_k=0$$
By misuse of notation, interpreting the sigma matrices as components of a vector, their linear combinations as scalar products and the implicit multiplication by a blank character, acting as operator application by evaluation from right to left, one has
$$\vec a  \cdot \vec\sigma \quad \vec b \cdot \vec \sigma = \vec a \cdot \vec b + i \ \sigma \cdot \vec a\times \vec b$$
After this lengthy introduction to the Pauli world, the eigenvalue equation can be written as
$$   ( a +\vec n \cdot \sigma) \ x = \lambda \ x $$
and so
$$(\vec n \cdot \vec \sigma)^2 \ x = \vec n^2 \ x = (\lambda -a)^2 x $$
so the two eigenvalues are the solutions of
$$(\lambda - a)^2- \vec n^2 =0$$
The coefficients of the representation of a matrix a is generated by the projection to the scalar part
$$A = a + \vec n \cdot \sigma \longrightarrow  a = \frac{1}{2} \text{Tr}\  A,\quad  n_k=\frac{1}{2} \text{Tr} \ \sigma_k A $$
With the scalar part absent, the  eigenvalues are simply the two roots of the (complex) length squared of the coefficients.
